# Python: What does this error message mean and why are we getting it?

Tags: python, excel, database, output, data-analysis

We are trying to create a new Excel file with nested data using Python code. Here is the code for reference:

```
`import glob
import pandas as pd
import re
import openpyxl

dp = pd.read_excel("UnpredictableDataMerge.xlsx", sheet_name ="Sheet1")
line_numbers = [4, 7]
print("Heey, we read")

dp_max = dp.groupby(['Subject', 'Date & Time', 'Trees Again', 'DifficultyLevel', 'Block', 'UpdatevsNonupdate', 'responsetimerecodeforACC', 'Nonupdate', 'Update'], sort=False).max()
dp_max = dp_max[["Total Training Time"]]
print("This worked. Good start. Yaaaay.s")

dp_max.to_excel('unpredictable_grouped_max_heregoesnothing.xlsx', index=True)
print("This worked. Yaaaay.s")

dp['Signal_Detection2'] = dp.loc[:, 'Signal_Detection']
dp_count = dp.groupby(['Subject', 'Signal_Detection'], sort=False).count()[["Signal_Detection2"]]

dp_count.to_excel('unpredictable_grouped_signal_count_heregoesnothing.xlsx', index=True) 


Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mxa210135\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3433, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-9-853a8bf5b14e>", line 5, in <module>
    dp = pd.read_excel("UnpredictableDataMerge.xlsx", sheet_name ="Sheet1")`
```

The code above is what we had tried and it had worked previously. We only added the 'Trees Again' variable and 'UpdatevsNonupdate', 'responsetimerecodeforACC', 'Nonupdate', and lastly 'Update'.
Please let me know if more information is needed and I will happily provide it.

We tried splitting the large file in half and run the code on both, but it did not work and gave us the same error message.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this before with large data sets. Try installing `lxml` as `openpyxl` will auto detect if the library is installed. Be sure to install it to the correct interpreter you are using.

```
py -m pip install lxml
```

Alternatively:

> Convert data to CSV file and use `pd.read_csv()`